# How could this IF formula me simplified? If possible

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have this formula:

```
=IF(C7="","",IF(C6>C5,IF(C7<=C5,0,(C7-C5)/(C6-C5)),IF(C6<C5,IF(C7>=C5,0,ABS(C7-C5)/(C5-C6)))))
```

referencing these cells:

[image]

Formula is a little confusing to the average person, however it gets me what I'm looking for.  Is there any way to simplify this?

Comment: `,IF(C6<C5,` <-- This nested `if` is superfluous as you can only reach this particular leg of your logic if it were already true. That being said you have no condition should C5=C6, but removing that superfluous bit will take care of that as well.

Comment: As for simplifying it, that would probably be better asked, in the future, at codereview.stackexchange.com as your formula works just fine, but you are looking for a review. I believe something like `=IF(ISBLANK(C7), "", IF(OR(AND(C5<=C7, C5<=C6), AND(C5>C7, C5>C6)), ABS((C7-C5)/(C5-C6)), 0))` would suffice though.

Comment: I may be having too much fun with this, but you could also do `=IF(ISBLANK(C7), "", ((C5<=C7) * (C5<=C6) +( C5>C7) * (C5>C6)) * ABS((C7-C5)/(C5-C6)))` Which is the same as the last one, but doing some boolean math instead of `AND()` and `OR()`. It may anger the next person that has to work on this thing though.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this is fun.

You have an implicit 0 in your first `IF` statement that I think should be a `""`. That would make the final undefined if the minimum achievement equals the max achievement.

If I'm correct, you could simplify to `=IFERROR(MAX((C7-C5)/(C6-C5),0),"")`.
To replicate your formula, you could simplify to `IF(C5<>"",IFERROR(MAX((C7-C5)/(C6-C5),0),0),"")`.

If you have Office 365, I recommend you use a `LET` function to further describe you code. The `LET` function allows you to define local variables in a formula. You can also add white space to better organize the formula.

Here is your formula using the let function. Its longer, but easier to tell what's going on:

```
=LET(
    Achiev0, C5,
    Achiev100, C6,
    Actual, C7,

    IF(
        Actual="",
        "",
        IF(Achiev100>Achiev0,
            IF(Actual<=Achiev0,
                0,
                (Actual-Achiev0)/(Achiev100-Achiev0)),
            IF(Achiev100<Achiev0,
                IF(Actual>=Achiev0,
                    0,
                    ABS(Actual-Achiev0)/(Achiev0-Achiev100)),
                0
    )))
)
```

If you define a few more variable, you can get something like this:

```
=LET(
    Achiev0, C5,
    Achiev100, C6,
    Actual, C7,

    NoValue, "",
    OutOfBounds, 0,
    Final, ABS((Actual-Achiev0)/(Achiev100-Achiev0)),

    IF(Actual = "", NoValue,
        IF(AND(Achiev0 <= Achiev100, Actual <= Achiev0), OutOfBounds,
            IF(AND(Achiev0 >= Achiev100, Achiev0 <= Actual), OutOfBounds,
                IFERROR(Final,OutOfBounds)
    )))
)
```

My simplification above would look like this:

```
=LET(
    Achiev0, C5,
    Achiev100, C6,
    Actual, C7,

    Final, (Actual-Achiev0)/(Achiev100-Achiev0),
    IFERROR(MAX(Final,0),"")
)
```

Comment: I didn't know about `=LET()`. That's pretty cool :)